# Spark - convert map to RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, scala-collections, rdd

I need to convert a map to a RDD so I can save it to ES but can't figure it out right now.

```
stream.foreachRDD {
    _.map(_._2).flatMap(l => (students zip l.split("~")).map{
      case (key, value) => key -> value
    })
   .toRDD().saveToEs() // convert map to RDD ???      
}
```

Any help ?

Comment: There is no `Map` here.

Comment: The result of your _map... should still be an RDD, so no need to convert it?

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul - How can I get the rdd here? .toRdd() doesn't exist from the result of my map.

Comment: That's because it already is an RDD, as far as I can see.

Comment: stream.foreachRDD{} returns an rdd if iam not right

Comment: @all - my bad, I wasn't importing the elastiscearch package. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

Basically, I just need to import the elasticsearch package in order to call saveToES method on the rdd.

```
import import org.elasticsearch.spark._

...
stream.foreachRDD {
_.map(_._2).flatMap(l => (students zip l.split("~")).map{
  case (key, value) => key -> value
})
.saveToEs("myindex/mytype") 
}
```

Thanks for the inputs!

Comment: A short explanation as to why your suggested code addresses the issue would make your contribution more valuable...